# Android : VerifyError from using picasaWebService from google

Tags: android, google-plus, picasa

I made thing simple to use a PicasaWebService to load a list of user albums

```
 PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("VideoAlbum");
                myService.setUserCredentials("email@blah", "password");

                URL feedUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/email@blah?kind=album");
                //URL feedUrl = new URL(String.format("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/%1$s?kind=album&access=all&token=%2$s", Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(client), token));

                UserFeed myUserFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, UserFeed.class);
                Log.w("PICASSO", "C " + myUserFeed.getAlbumEntries().size() );
                for (AlbumEntry myAlbum : myUserFeed.getAlbumEntries()) {
                    System.out.println("PICASA ALBUM "+ myAlbum.getTitle().getPlainText());
                }
```

When one the code I received,

> 11-27 16:21:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7077): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-122693 11-27 16:21:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7077):
>   java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService
>   11-27 16:21:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7077):   at
>   com.innovative.fragment.PicassaFragment$1.run(PicassaFragment.java:79)

What does the error mean....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GData API client libraries are not made explicitly for Android so you need to take care of a few problems. If you get the VerifyError, then you are missing the following libraries of the JavaMail port for the Android platform in your build path:

- activation.jar
- additional.jar
- mail.jar

You can download these libraries from the [JavaMail port website](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list) and then you will no longer have this compile time exception.